# Phaser Generated Texture isn't working

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Attempting to make a randomized texture, I have the following code:

```
//doesn't work
var selections = [".","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","A","B","D","E","F"]


var d = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
    var inner = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 15; j++){
      var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * selections.length);
      var item = selections[idx];
      inner.push(item);
    }
    d.push(inner.join(''));
}

//console.log(burd, data)
console.log(d);


game.create.texture('rand',d, pixelWidth, pixelHeight);
```

For some reason it doesn't load (or just shows as background)
I've tried just using hard coded values and works fine.

```
//works
var burd = [
"A682EA1D51D8D46",
"5.1628F1.F81757",
"1A6F2672B234AE1",
"B.8BB42746AFA22",
"E4.113385.D1.D.",
"6EF22BA.66181D3",
"7E18A7DD6F8F3D2",
".D47D225761427D",
"B4BDA5DE..778E7",
"1B46.BEF48321D8",
"FF6.7.347746D2.",
"A2AF57B4B4F4.DD",
"EAD335264158B14",
"A133FB31E4.E728",
"FAF52EBF7.3E81D"];

game.create.texture('burd', burd, pixelWidth, pixelHeight);
game.add.sprite(300, 300, 'burd');
```

Is there any error in my code? An issue with phaser? (using 2.6.2),
Full code here: https://gist.github.com/blakedallen/f771d8e0615ff8d35f0630db6a10bd6d

Answer (score 1):

All below tested on Phaser CE v2.10.3, but i think it should be same for your version.

Im wondering how can 2nd example of your code work(when generating 'burd').
On any cases texture creation is async action and usage of created texture should happens when that texture has been created. e.g

```
this.game.create.texture('rand', d, pixelWidth, pixelHeight, Phaser.Create.PALETTE_C64, true, () => {
    game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'rand');
}, this);
```

[image]